# How to get button value on conditional statement with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am having a hard time trying to get the value of a button when it is clicked using JQuery.
I am able to change the button value with other statements, but I need to check the value when it gets clicked again. Right now it looks like..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        if ($("#btnSubmit").attr('value', "Submit")) {
            SubmitData();
            ClearTextBoxes();
        }
        else if ($("#btnSubmit").attr('value',"Update")) {
            SubmitUpdateData();
            ClearTextBoxes();

        }
    });
});
```

and I have also tried..

```
.val() == "Submit"
.attr('value') == "Submit"
.text == "Submit"
```

But none of these has worked.

**EDIT**

Here is my button..

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Comment: are you using  `<button>` or `type="submit"`?

Comment: @Phuti, I just made an edit and added the button...Its a type=button.

Comment: What you have right now is not comparing but assigning the value (and if I'm correct, it will always go through the if condition and never reach the else part). The first 2 that you show should work fine. Do you get any error with them?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, you are correct it is just assigning, i ended up back at that part. I tried the other ways that I mentioned and those failed me. I am looking at it again and yea it won't work at all

Comment: Why don't you use use a Class to mark it rather than the Value attribute?

Comment: @SteveK, I am not sure what you mean. What I am doing is changing the value of the button when a row gets clicked in a grid then I was trying to have a condition on it to call another function based on its value

Comment: @Chris is the id unique?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, yes, its the only button i have on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try comparing the value of the `button`.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var val = $(this).val();
    if(val === 'Submit'){
        SubmitData();
        ClearTextBoxes();
       //you can also change the value of the button here
       $(this).val('Update');
    }else if(val === 'Update'){
        SubmitUpdateData();
        ClearTextBoxes();
       //you can also change the value of the button here
       $(this).val('Submit');
    }
   });
  });
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val === 'Submit'){
            //SubmitData();
            //ClearTextBoxes();
            $(this).val('Update');
        }else if(val === 'Update'){
            //SubmitUpdateData();
            //ClearTextBoxes();
            $(this).val('Submit');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn">
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, I debugged at the same time and couldn't even reach it. It has to happen on the button click function...Or was I supposed to put this in the click function?

Comment: Got it, had to put it in the click event. Thank you.